# What will happen if big file will be loaded in memory buffer in C webserver

Tags: c, memory, tcp, webserver

I am making a simple web server in C to serve static files in educational purposes. I made a function that sends file to client, and it allocates memory block for whole file. What if server hardware has 4 GB of memory, and client requested big, for example, database file that has 5 GB in size. Wouldn't it crash my application?

body of my serve_file function (please, note that error handling is omitted):

```
long fsize;
FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
fsize = ftell(fp);
rewind(fp);

char *buf = (char*) malloc(fsize);

fread(buf, fsize, 1, fp);

Server_TCP_Send(socket, buf, fsize);
fclose(fp);
free(buf);
```

Comment: Not if you code it in a half decent way. Allocating one big chunk of memory and reading the whole file in one go is obviously not the best way. Can you think of any other options?

Comment: Yes, I thought about sending file chunk-by-chunk but will it be fast enough for bigfiles? Also, there were some problems in implementation of this, but that't another question/problem I think

Comment: Define "fast enough". Fast enough for google? Probably not. Fast enough for an assignment or home project. Probably. Anyway, the limiting factor is likely to be the network which won't be affected much by using sensible chunk sizes. And tuning for performance should not be done prematurely.

Comment: somewhat related I think,, consider using the [`splice`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/splice) function. This _should_ utilize zero copy, which will be faster than copying the file data up to user space, then back to kernel space. I've never actually used this before but I think it should apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is to read and serve the data in manageable chunks using a loop. That way it won't matter how large the file is. Your approach may or may not cause a system crash. If it doesn't crash it is likely to start paging your data to disk using virtual memory. This will cause lots of thrashing and slow down your system, which is especially bad if other programs are trying to run.

Comment: Thanks. Like I said in comment under my question, will sending by chunks be fast enough?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem as long as they're not too small. I have done this many times. The exact "best" size might be difficult to determine, but I would use anywhere from 1Kb to 1 Mb. If you have lots of memory, you could go higher, but it might not matter because network bandwidth is probably going to be the limiting factor, not memory.

Answer (score 2):

> What if server hardware has 4 GB of memory, and client requested big, for example, database file that has 5 GB in size. Wouldn't it crash my application?

Maybe.  Maybe not.  Nothing in the C standard speaks directly to this question.  Even in practice, it is not necessarily true that size of allocated objects supported by your C implementation is limited to the size of your physical memory.  Modern machines have virtual memory systems, with which it is conceivable that an allocation such as you describe could be supported.  If indeed the allocation succeeds, then there's no special reason to think that your server would crash.

The main risk here is that *you don't check* whether the allocation succeeds.  In the plausible event that it fails, the `malloc()` call will return a null pointer.  Passing a null pointer as the first argument of `fread()` will produce undefined behavior.  That is pretty likely to manifest as a crash in a case such as this, but it is not required to do so.  If you check the return value of your `malloc()` call then you can instead fail gracefully instead of crashing.

I note that you don't check the return value of your `fread()`, either.  If it fails, then you could end up sending garbage to the client.  As a general rule, you should check the return values of your function calls for error indicators if indeed you care whether any error occurred.

With that said, there are indeed better ways to do what you are trying to do.  Aside from the significant risk of failure, reading the whole file into memory before sending it will likely introduce a noticeable delay before the transfer to the client actually starts.  Quite possibly enough for an automated or organic timeout.  Reading in smaller chunks very likely would be considerably faster in that sense.  There are other alternatives, too, such as *mapping* the file into memory rather than actually reading it.

Comment: I mentioned that I omitted error handling to reduce code size here. Surely, all return values should be checked. Thanks for reply anyway